# How to Get Last Inserted id in Django Slug?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a unique slug, on the basis of last inserted id in my Django Project, But I am unable to get last Inserted id in my Slug, Please elt me know Where I am mistaking.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class ProjectStatus(models.Model):

city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                        default= None,
                        related_name="ProjectStatusCity",
                        help_text=f"Type: Int, Values: Select City Name.")

name = models.CharField(max_length=190,
                        default=None,
                        help_text=f"Type: string, Default: None, Values: Enter Project Status.")

slug = models.SlugField(max_length=190,
                        unique=True,
                        default='',
                        editable=False,
                        help_text=f"Type: String, Default: None, Values: Enter Slug.")

meta_title = models.CharField(max_length=190,
                        default=None,
                        help_text=f"Type: string, Default: None, Values: Enter Project Status.")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    kwargs = {
        'pk': self.id,
        'slug': self.slug
    }
    return reverse('article-pk-slug-detail', kwargs=kwargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    value = self.name + "-" + "prsid" + "-" + "city" + "-" + "s"
    self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want the last inserted id after `s` in  this line (`value = self.name + "-" + "prsid" + "-" + "s"`), And I have relation with `city` so I want `city name` also here, Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: obj = ProjectStatus.objects.latest('id')

Comment: id = ProjectStatus.objects.latest('id')['id']